# How to set max date in a kendodatepicker every time another date is chosed

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

i have two kendodatepickers "startDate" and "endDate". I want every time the user set a date in startdate, establish the max date one month forward from the selected date to pick in endDate datepicker.

I am setting up the first time in this way:

```
 $("#datStartDate").kendoDatePicker({
        start: "month",
        depth: "year",
        format: "dd/MM/yyyy",
        dateInput: true,
        change: (e) => {                
            return moc.rangeStartDate("datStartDate", "datEndDate");
        },
        min: new Date(1900, 0, 1),
        max: new Date(),
        value: new Date()
    });

    $("#datEndDate").kendoDatePicker({
        start: "month",
        depth: "year",
        format: "dd/MM/yyyy",
        dateInput: true,
        max: new Date(),
        change: (e) => {
            return moc.rangeEndDate("datStartDate", "datEndDate");
        },
        value: new Date()
    });
```

I tried this to set the max value, each time the startDate picker is cheanged:

```
$("#datStartDate").change(() => {
        let startDate = ($("#datStartDate").val()).split("/");
        console.log("cambio de fecha", parseInt(startDate[2]), parseInt(startDate[1]), parseInt(startDate[0]))
        let datePicker = $("#datEndDate").data("kendoDatePicker");
        datePicker.max(new Date(parseInt(startDate[2]), parseInt(startDate[1]), parseInt(startDate[0])));
        datePicker.value(new Date(parseInt(startDate[2]), parseInt(startDate[1]), parseInt(startDate[0])))
    })
```

It doesnt works and i dont get an error. How can i do this? Thank you so much for you time.

I am using this:

- KendoUI
- JavaScript
- ASP .NET MVC
- RAZOR
- jquery

Comment: Maybe this could work,(untested) https://jsfiddle.net/h68uoxtn/

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen I had this exception "Exception unhandled: TypeError: dateEndDatePicker.setOptions is not a function"

Answer (score 0):

you can use it in **Jquery**

```
function startChange() {
    var endPicker = $("#dtpStartDate").data("kendoDatePicker"),
    startDate = this.value();

    if (startDate) {
        startDate = new Date(startDate);
        startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate());
        endPicker.max(startDate + 30);
    }
}

function endChange() {
    var startPicker = $("#dtpEndDate").data("kendoDatePicker"),
    endDate = this.value();

    if (endDate) {
        endDate = new Date(endDate);
        endDate.setDate(endDate.getDate());
        startPicker.max(endDate - 30);
    }
}
```

and in razor files you can create datepickers like this

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">@Html.LabelFor(m => m.StartDate)</label>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        @(Html.Kendo().DatePickerFor(m => m.StartDate)
            .HtmlAttributes(new { @Id = "dtpStartDate", style = "width:100%", required = "required", validationMessage = "Select Start Date" })
            .Events(e => e.Change("startChange")))
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">@Html.LabelFor(m => m.EndDate)</label>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        @(Html.Kendo().DatePickerFor(m => m.EndDate)
            .HtmlAttributes(new { @Id = "dtpEndDate", style = "width:100%", required = "required", validationMessage = "Select End Date" })
            .Events(e=>e.Change("endChange")))
    </div>
</div>
```